Uvicorn with Django Channels: distinguish server restart from client disconnect
I'm planning to migrate from Daphne to Uvicorn due to it's better performance. Uvicorn uses graceful shutdown which causes connections closing any time server becomes unavailable, like simple restart. I need to keep service interruptions seamless for clients and reconnect automatically like nothing happened. With Daphne it runs disconnect couroutine only when it comes from client side.
Is there any way to disable graceful disconnections in Uvicorn (probably not the best way)? Or to handle it differently in Django Channels?
